# Determining permissions for files uploaded via FTP

Tags: php, ftp

So I'm working on some legacy/maintenance code, and there's a file upload that uses FTP, specifically ftp_login() and ftp_put().

Anyway, whenever I uploaded a file, it has very low permissions - only the user that uploads has write permission. I want all uploaded files to have all permissions enabled.

How would I go about this? I can't see anyway of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ftp_chmod`](http://php.net/ftp_chmod) to change the permission of a file on an FTP server from PHP.

```
ftp_chmod($conn, 0777, $file);
```

The above line will - if successful - grant all permissions to everybody on `$file`.

Comment: Ah, so I'd just run that after I ran the upload? or before?

Comment: after. it changes the permissions on a existing file

Comment: It doesn't seem to want to do this. Wouldn't I need advanced permissions before doing this?